# How to use a map to fire async request but get an aggregated result?

Tags: dictionary, asynchronous, dart

I have the Code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future<int> expensiveCallFromALib(int value) async {
  print('expensiveCall($value)');
  return value + 1;
}

test() {
  Map<String, int>input = {"one":1, "two":2};
  Map result = {};

  print("A");
  input.forEach((String key, int value) {
    expensiveCallFromALib(value).then((int value) {
      result[key] = value;
    });
    print("B");
  });
  print("C");

  print(result);

}

main() {
  test();
}
```

... with the output

```
A
B
B
C
{}
expensiveCall(1)
expensiveCall(2)
```

... but I want

```
A
B
expensiveCall(1)
B
expensiveCall(2)
C
{one: 2, two: 3}
```

The Point is, that I cant change the expensiveCallFromALib method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test() async {
  Map<String, int>input = {"one":1, "two":2};
  Map result = {};

  print("A");
  for(final key in input.keys) {
    int value = await expensiveCallFromALib(input[key]);
      result[key] = value;

    print("B");
  }
  print("C");
  print('result: $result');
}
```

The output is not exactly how you want it but I guess it's close enough ;-)

```
HTML OUTPUT
CONSOLE
A
expensiveCall(1)
B
expensiveCall(2)
B
C
result: {one: 2, two: 3}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e0b0ede8de40747a7beaa00b6ed0afa5)